# WF4 Argument as Property

Tags: properties, workflow-foundation-4, variable-assignment, arguments

My scenario is the following:
I have a workflow (lets call it customActivity1) that do the basic actions for my system. I also have another workflow (customActivity2) that uses customActivity1 and do higher level actions. When I call customActivity1, I must pass on a few parameters, like Boolean or String values. I want to show some of these parameters as a checkbox or combobox (so the developer of customActivity2 can pass on only valid values) and found out that I can do that by setting the argument as PROPERTY (instead of In).
By doing a research, I also found out that you can’t directly use this argument in expressions, so I keep getting errors on my customActivity1.

That said and knowing that I need to narrow what the designer can pass on, how could I do that without using an activity designer or where could I find an answer?

I also attached two pictures, one of what I need and the other of the error I’m getting.
[image: What I need]

[image: The error I'm getting]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "I also have another workflow (customActivity2) that uses customActivity1" (uses? how? is CA2 placed in CA1?) and by what you mean by "pass on" (do you wish to bind an InArgument in CA1 to a public variable defined in CA2?)

Comment: I mean that CA1 is inside CA2. And By "pass on" I mean bind the CA2 public variables to CA1 arguments. The problem is that I want to use Properties instead of InArguments on CA1

Answer (score 0):

The reason an InArgument only shows you a text field instead of a checkbox is because they are expressions not literal values. There is still type checking though, if you enter the value 1 you get the error message that an integer cannot be converted into a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.  You can only bind to InArguments.

If you bind an InArgument and look at the xaml, you'll see something like this:

```
<p1:MyActivity MyInArgument="[BoundValue]" ...
```

The Workflow Runtime knows how to handle these.  It doesn't know how to handle binding POCO properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to model data flow but want to have a different user experience in the property grid I recommed using arguments (as they convey data flow semantics) and customizing the property grid for those arguments. There is a sample that demonstrates how to do this in the WF4 samples (sample readme available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834515.aspx)